# What is wrong with this command from Scipy?

Tags: python, scipy, linear-regression

I am trying to see if the results that I get from my model are statistically relevant or not by calculating the observed t.

```
from scipy import stats

linregress=stats.linregress(retornos['ineg'],retornos['Modelo'])
linregress2=stats.linregress(retornos['ineg'],retornos['m3070'])
linregress3=stats.linregress(retornos['ineg'],retornos['m70100'])`

T=(linregress.intercept)/linregress.intercept_stderr
T2=(linregress2.intercept)/linregress2.intercept_stderr
T3=(linregress3.intercept)/linregress3.intercept_stderr
```

I am running this code and the return that I get is:

**AttributeError: 'LinregressResult' object has no attribute 'intercept_stderr'**

---

Does anyone know what is wrong or how to fix it?

Scipy documentation:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html

---

I am new here, so I apologize if I made any mistakes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check your version of Scipy, `intercept_stderr` was added in 1.6

Comment: Usually changes like this are documented with notes like `(new in v 1.6), but it seems that  the enhancement process was a bit messy, https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/12983.  Also in the release notes, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.6.0.html#scipy-stats-improvements

Comment: Downloaded the 1.6 version and it worked. Thank you very much.